# Reading from text file skips first line

Tags: c, file, pointers, text, while-loop

I'm using strtok to read from a file that looks like this. Thanks to the answer of my last question, the seg fault went away. However, I'm now having a problem of the the read in file, not being read on the first line

Once again: I have a file that looks like this (test.txt)

```
5f6
2f6
```

And a c file that looks like this:

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    char buf[100];
    char *ptr;
    char *ptr2;
    char *ptr3;
    char *ptr4;
    int a,b,c,d;
    FILE *file;

    initscr();
    cbreak();
    noecho();

    if (argc > 1)
     {
        file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        if (file == NULL) //doesn't return null
            return -1;
        while (fgets(buf,100,file) != NULL)
         {
            ptr  = strtok(buf,"f");
            ptr2 = strtok(NULL," ");
            ptr3 = strtok(NULL,"f");
            ptr4 = strtok(NULL," ");
            if (ptr != NULL)
                a = atoi(ptr);
            if (ptr2 != NULL)
                b = atoi(ptr2);
            if (ptr3 != NULL)
                c = atoi(ptr3);
            if (ptr4 != NULL)
                d = atoi(ptr4);

            mvprintw(0,0,"Values are a %d b %d c %d d %d",a,b,c,d);
         }
     }
    refresh();
    getchar();
    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```

from the text file, the values should be(EXPECTED OUTPUT): `a = 5, b = 6, c = 2, d = 6;`

But the program outputs: `a = 2, b = 6, c = 0, d = 0`

I've tried to modify entries of the text file(change the values around), but that doesn't seem to yield any improvement. I've also tried to change directory, re write this code in another directory with a new file (in case it was some sort of a memory issue, but all to no avail.) Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You `strtok` on `str`(which isn't defined?), but `fgets` into `buf`. Is this a copy-and-paste error? You also require command-line arguments, but always read `"test.txt"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things: `fgets` will read lines, i.e. until either a new-line character is found or the buffer is full. With your current file layout, you can't get all four values with one `fgets`.

You actually read two lines from the file, but you overwrite the results, because you don't advance the cursor position; you always write at (0, 0). So you only see the last line's values.

Comment: So printing a,b at one cursor position and c,d at another is what you're suggesting? I'm not sure I fully understand your first point.

Comment: If you don't advance the cursor (or use a printing function that does automatically), you won't see all results, because you constantly overwrite them. You should probably use `printw`, which advances the cursor automatically.

Comment: About the lines: After the first `fgets` call, `buf` is `"5f6\n"`, including the new-line character. That's how far the file has been read. The program doesn't know about the next line, `"2f6\n"`, yet. So it finds only two tokens. So either change your file format to have all desired values on one line or introduce a second call to `fgets`.

Comment: I've tried your advancing cursor suggestion, but it lead to the same result. As for fgets, if buf is "5f6\n" then why are the values in the next line being printed instead?

Comment: You have two problems, but you think it is only one. Please separate them and solve the file reading first, but _don't_ use ncurses. Just print the values into the console. Or use a debugger and look at the values. Whatever. I can't put my proposed solution any clearer than I have already.